# Python find if all values are equal in dict of dicts

Tags: python

Given a dictionary,

```
data =  {
            '1234': {'jid':1341, 'msg':'' , 'status':0},
            '5678': {'jid':1342, 'msg':'' , 'status':1},
            '1112': {'jid':1343, 'msg':'' , 'status':0},
            '1314': {'jid':1344, 'msg':'' , 'status':1}
        }
```

Using Python, what is the most optimal way to check if all `status` values are 1?

The way I am trying to do is to iterate through the dictionary and set a flag to 0 if at least one of the `status` values is 0.

Comment: What you're describing sounds fine, what's the problem with it?

Comment: I was wondering if there was a better solution.

Comment: "Better" in what way? Given that you don't show your solution: better than what, even?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `all` function and iterate over the values of your dictionary:

```
>>> all(x['status'] == 1 for x in data.values())
False
```

Comment: Please note: this _does_ short-circuit. As soon as it finds one element for which the condition is false it will not iterate further.